# Use OR with IF in formula field for images

Tags: formula-field

I am with a doubt, as you can see in the formula I want to show different images depending on the picklist value that he choses, and until know the formula it was ok, but now I want that in the 3 if, he can choose more than one value: 
eg: it can choose "Enviado para a FPT" or "Enviado para a BCE" or "Enviado para a APT"  and the image will be the same, I know that I need to use a OR but I am stuck.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c, "Novo"), IMAGE("/resource/PB25","Novo",100,100),
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c, "Enviado para o Clube"), IMAGE ("/resource/PB50",
 "Enviado para o Clube",100,100),
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c, "Enviado para a FPT") , IMAGE ("/resource/PB75",
 "Enviado para a FPT",100,100),
IF(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c, "Fechado - Resolvido"), IMAGE("/resource/PB100","Fechado - Resolvido",100,100),null))))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
IF(OR(ISPICKVAL(Estado__c, "Enviado para a FPT"),ISPICKVAL(Estado__c, "Enviado para a BCE"),ISPICKVAL(Estado__c, "Enviado para a APT")) , IMAGE ("/resource/PB75",
 "Enviado para a FPT",100,100)
```

The OR is very simple to use

> OR(fn1,fn2,fn3)

where fn1,fn2 and fn3 are logical statements or functions

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably choose to do this with the `CASE()` function and srap the `OR()` as it keeps down the nesting and `ISPICKVAL` statements. With decent formatting it makes the formula very easy to read an understand, and should you decide to use a different image for one of the values later, the change is super easy to make.

```
CASE (Estado__c,
  "Novo",                 IMAGE("/resource/PB25","Novo",100,100),
  "Enviado para o Clube", IMAGE ("/resource/PB50", "Enviado para o Clube",100,100),
  "Enviado para a FPT",   IMAGE ("/resource/PB75", "Enviado para a FPT",100,100),
  "Enviado para a BCE",   IMAGE ("/resource/PB75", "Enviado para a FPT",100,100),
  "Enviado para a APT",   IMAGE ("/resource/PB75", "Enviado para a FPT",100,100),
  "Fechado - Resolvido",  IMAGE("/resource/PB100","Fechado - Resolvido",100,100),
  null
)
```